# PhoneGap build Give Error while trying to build Android APK

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

PhoneGap Build suddenly give errors and don't build apk file for android.

The error are.

```html
Build Date: 2014-12-28 12:02:59 +0000
----------------------------------------------
debug: 
/home/ec2-user/gimlet/var/android/3.6.3/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.
    at /home/ec2-user/gimlet/var/android/3.6.3/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:158:19
    at _fulfilled (/home/ec2-user/gimlet/var/android/3.6.3/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/ec2-user/gimlet/var/android/3.6.3/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/ec2-user/gimlet/var/android/3.6.3/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:760:13)
    at /home/ec2-user/gimlet/var/android/3.6.3/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:821:14
    at flush (/home/ec2-user/gimlet/var/android/3.6.3/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

Any help please

Comment: I am getting the same error. You are not doing anything wrong, the issue is on their side. They will resolve soon.

Comment: Thanks, I also post the issue on phonegap build support and also see many people having same error.

Comment: Issue appears to be resolved and Android builds are working again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is a temporary problem of the PhoneGap Build service.**
All you can do is trying it again, later.
I got the same error today, several times. Sometimes it was a success, sometimes it failed.
I recognized that removing Hydration helped getting a successful build, more often.